# web grabber

Tags: java

in java how the url is downloaded and save it in to a local directory. More over i want a offline view of that downloaded url(especially the html content).

Comment: could you explain "More over i want a offline view of that downloaded url(especially the html content)." a bit in detail please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code for sucking HTML into strings. Note, this doesn't pull the content (images, etc...), just the HTML! Enjoy :)

```
try
{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

    String html = "";
    String line = "";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        html += line;
    }

    //Now you can do what you please with
    //the HTML content (save it locally, parse, etc...)
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Error handling
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using Jakarta's HTTPClient over the Java IO classes, the former dealing with redirects, etc automatically.